# Spring MVC GetMapping does not take effect

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I'm trying Spring MVC,I tried @RequestMapping and @GetMampping annotation. There is something wired that @GetMapping doest not take effect.
Below is the code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/service")
public class ServiceEntry {

    @RequestMapping(path="/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String mainPage(){
        return "Hello,Information";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/hello2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String page2(){
        return "hello2!";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/test1")
    @ResponseBody
    public String page_test1(){
        return "Get method 1";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/test2")
    @ResponseBody
    public String page_test2(){
        return "Get method 2";
    }
}
```

While I visit /service/hello or /service/hello2 it works, but /service/test1 or /service/test2 does not work, please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In `RequestMapping` you can use parameter `path` but not in
>   `GetMapping`. You can do like this: `GetMapping("/test1")` or
>   `GetMapping(value="/test1")`

Answer (score 1):

Use `value` instead `path`.  EG:  `@GetMapping(value="/test2")`

Comment: Can you use below code. I think it will be works for you. @GetMapping("/test2")